# AngularJS - Scroll to top on swipe-left or right

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

**I'm trying to create a project in angularJS and ionic where there is a slidebox with three slide and each slide contains some content. I want to scroll to top each time I change the slide.**

I have supposed that the better way to do this is use on-swipe-left/right methods but I didn't manage to do my task and so, each time I change slide it doesn't change scroll position. Someone have some ideas of how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using Ionic, you can (should) use the [**$ionicScrollDelegate's**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicScrollDelegate/) method [scrollTo()](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicScrollDelegate/#scrollTo). By calling `$ionicScrollDelegate.scrollTo(0, 0, true)` you're scrolling to the top. If you don't want the scrolling to be animated, call the method with `false` as the third parameter or omit it.

Comment: Thank for your answer I have't seen the documentation of scroll. I have used scrollTop() methods.